# HTTP Post in Angular using FormData causes Unexpected Token error

Tags: angular, http, post

I currently have this section in a function of an Ionic application that uses Angular and Capacitor. The function is for uploading a file using a FormData post.

```
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append(name, blobFile, "TestName");
        data.append('fileId', params.fileId);
        data.append('pagenumber', params.pageNum); 
        data.append('appid', this.appMod.appId);
        data.append('sessionid', this.appMod.sessionId);
        ...
        return this.http.post(
             webServiceUrl,
             data,
             {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': undefined})},
             );
```

With `this.http` being the Angular `HttpClient`. When this section runs, it reaches the `http.post` however what is returned is the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Checking network activity, this post never actually sends out any network requests leading me to believe this is not an issue with the backend

From what we have tested we tried setting `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and adding `responseType: 'text'` in the HttpOptions however both did not fix the issue. In addition I have repeatedly made sure that the `webServiceUrl` is correct.

I have no idea what could be causing this issue so any insight will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It seems there were some earlier versions that [had issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37597) with detecting or setting `multipart/form-data` - the `Content-Type` you should be using as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/2307877).

I have verified, when using your exact code in Angular 14, the `Content-Type` is correctly set and the request is sent if no `Content-Type` is specified when passing a `FormData` object to the `HttpClient`'s `post` method.

```js
    return this.http.post(webServiceUrl, data, {
      // headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': '' }),
    });
```

You might still have to set `responseType: 'text'` as you indicated earlier.

So your resolution will be a combination of

1. Checking your (possibly old) Angular version for problems in this area (see link above)
2. Not setting a `Content-Type` as it's inferred from the passed object
3. Making sure you have set your `responseType` to match the server's return type
4. Checking if you have any `HttpInterceptor`s that might be overriding `Content-Type` or causing conflicts otherwise